# how to get message history (message archiving) using jabber-net

Tags: asp.net, xmpp

I'm making simple **XMPP** client using Jabber-Net. To send simple message,  i need a simple example on how to retrieve message history?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this extension is supported by jabber-net out of the box. You would have to implement the protocol classes yourself and write some extensions.
Or see if some if someone else has done this already and shared the code somewhere.